# Low-cost centimeter-level accurate satellite positioning (GNSS/GPS)

Tags: gps, accuracy, precision, rtklib

I am looking for a low-cost (< US$500) GNSS/GPS setup with a centimeter precision without much HW hacking. I am not able to produce my PCB or do any soldering (though I would do that if there is no other way) so a kind of a easy-to-assemble setup would be welcome. I know about the [$900 Piksi thing](http://swiftnav.com/piksi.html) but that is still too expensive for me. It seems like cm precision should be possible for much less - like employing a 50 USD raw GPS sensor with an antenna and ordinary PC with RTKLIB software.

I am not sure if it is better to use two GPS sensor setup for RTK (one base station and one for rover) or whether I can get the corrective DGPS data elsewhere (my region is Czech Republic - there seems to be [national grid](http://czepos.cuzk.cz/) here allowing to stream correction data for reasonable cost).

My application will be in a passenger car so I will not be limited with power source - no low power needed although that would be nice. I will be using the position readings within OpenCV - so I need to get the data into C/C++ code. The application is data collection so I can use raw GPS post-processing.

**EDIT:** [I was recommended](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/a/4317/1021) a $150 U-BLOX LEA-6T USB board that would make a $300 sum for dual unit setup without the host HW (probably 2 x PC or Raspberry Pi?) and software. As software RTKLIB could probably be used although I have zero experience with either (HW & SW) of these.

Also, there seems to be the [NAVIO board from EMLID](http://www.emlid.com/) in development and hopefully to be released soon. This will probably offer an "out of the box" RTK solution (both HW & SW) at an [estimated price of $165](http://diydrones.com/profiles/blogs/navio-rtk-demonstration) for board (see comments on that link). They made some [RTK demonstration](http://www.emlid.com/rtk-gps-demonstration/) ([theory here](http://www.emlid.com/introduction-to-rtk-gps/)) and also some [Real-time OS tests](http://www.emlid.com/raspberry-pi-real-time-kernel-available-for-download/).

Comment: there's also a GPS RAW Reciever, but till the moment there's no echo about good results http://navspark.mybigcommerce.com/ns-raw-carrier-phase-raw-measurement-output-gps-receiver/

http://navspark.mybigcommerce.com/ns-raw-carrier-phase-raw-measurement-output-gps-receiver/

Comment: Thanks for a link! I just found few nice pages with "rtklib raspberry pi" google search: http://tubbyaustin.blogspot.cz/2013/06/rtklib-on-raspberry-pi.html and http://gnss.co/?p=52 these guys report the u-blox LEA-xT or NEO-xT range chipsets should have cheap raw data, but I am struggling with purchasing availability within EU. Seems like the NS-RAW would work "out of the box" with RTKLIB on a PC?

Comment: NS-RAW yes it works out of the box that said in their indiegogo campaing https://www.indiegogo.com/projects/navspark-arduino-compatible-with-gps-gnss-receiver

Comment: but how to compare different u-blox chips ?

Comment: Emlid now offers U-blox NEO-6T USB dongle with raw GPS data for $50. It should be compatible with RTKLIB. See http://www.emlid.com/shop/u-blox-neo-usb/.

Comment: The successor of NAVIO and NAVIO+ is now called [REACH](http://www.emlid.com/reach/). There is a [RTK kit](http://www.emlid.com/shop/reach-rtk-kit/) for $570 available.

Comment: The currently cheapest GPS module (just a sensor without CPU/computer) with RAW data support I could find is this one: [UBLOX NEO-M8T TIME & RAW](http://www.csgshop.com/product.php?id_product=205) from CSGShop - they told me they have warehouses in both EU and USA so all prices are final (VAT included). They have also more expensive modules with integrated antenna etc.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [Adafruit Ultimate GPS Breakout - 66 channel w/10 Hz](http://www.adafruit.com/product/746), it has position accuracy of <3 meter, velocity accuracy of 0.1 meter per second and cost around 40$. For a working model with Raspberry Pi, here is a [tutorial](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-ultimate-gps-on-the-raspberry-pi?view=all).

Comment: How do you get from "<3 meter" down to *centimeter* accuracy?

Comment: post processing a quick search: https://www.unavco.org/software/data-processing/postprocessing/postprocessing.html

Comment: Post processing depends on more data than you can get out of simple NEMA sentence positioning info.  You need the raw satellite timing info that works with the RTK postprocessing.

Answer (score 2):

From my research on the WWW, the best cheapest working solutions seems to be the [REACH](http://www.emlid.com/reach/) at the moment (December 2015). They have [RTK kit](http://www.emlid.com/shop/reach-rtk-kit/) for $570 available.

The board is the successor of NAVIO and the NAVIO+ board.

[image: reach board]

Comment: The u-Blox NEO-M8N module shown in the picture, with the current(2017) flash/firmware, has disabled the NAV-RAWX data so they no longer work as RTKLIB Ready.  If you can find a LEA-6T or NEO-M8T based board, it would work.